# Setting a variable derived from a SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, automation, toad

I'm attempting to use the Toad automation tool for the first time. My problem is that I can't seem to set a variable from a SQL statement. When I execute the [simple] SQL statement (`select max(date_col) from some_table`) outside of the automation script, it works as expected.

How do I set this variable? What steps do I need to take? (I've tried searching around for this on Google, but I'm having issues finding anything useful)

Comment: Are you talking about something like `DECLARE @variable DATETIME; SET @variable = (SELECT MAX(date_col) FROM some_table;`?

Comment: no, I can do this in a t-sql script easily enough. I'm talking about using Toad's automation tool (from Toad, Tools > Automation)

Comment: [Here is my post](http://toadforsqlserver.com/thread.jspa?threadID=38231&tstart=0) from the toadworld.com forums

Comment: Ok. I figured it had to be more involved than that :) Have you seen this blog post on their site? It's a little dated but might help you out: http://www.toadworld.com/Blogs/tabid/67/EntryId/498/Automation-Variables-Automation-variables-using-datasets.aspx

Comment: Thanks @JOpuckman - that lead me down the right path. Basically, I couldn't use the variable names without prefixing and suffixing them with `#` signs.

i.e. I was doing `today = updated` when I should have been doing `#today# = #updated#`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to store max(date_col) value into a variable. 
And I think below statement should work:

```
SELECT @variable = MAX(date_col) FROM some_table
```

Comment: see [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144670/setting-a-variable-derived-from-a-sql-statement#comment19588534_14144670) . I have other things I need to accomplish so I need to use the automation tool built into Toad and not a normal t-sql script.